# Attempting to create a read-only property attribute - getter returns initialized value, direct access returns changed value

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7, properties

Although I may be very confused as to what the [`property()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) function does, I'm trying to use it to create an attribute which is read-only. Ideally, I'd like to be able to refer to the attribute directly but not be allowed to assign to it. When experimenting, I got this very curious behavior:

```
>>> class Boo(object):
...     def __init__(self, x):
...             self.__x = x
...     def getx(self):
...             return self.__x
...     x = property(getx)
... 
>>> b = Boo(1)
>>> b.__x = 2
>>> b.getx()
1
>>> b.__x
2
```

I'd like to add that when I used `x` and `_x` as the attribute names, reassigning the attribute caused the getter to return the changed value, i.e. both `b.getx()` and `b.x`/`b._x` gave me `2`.

I realize that I'm using `x` as the property name, though, but when I tried the following I got an `AttributeError` in my `__init__()`:

```
>>> class Boo(object):
...     def __init__(self, x):
...             self.__x = x
...     def getx(self):
...             return self.__x
...     __x = property(getx)
... 
>>> b = Boo(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: I'd like to add that I wasn't trying to get a truly private variable, just one that couldn't be modified after it was assigned. (I realize that I can't have my cake and eat it too - Python's not Java and so forth. Was just curious about the behavior and how far I could get with `property()`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here has nothing to do with `property`, but with double-underscore attributes, which are subject to what's called ["Private name mangling"](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers).

```
>>> b = Boo(1)
>>> '__x' in dir(b)
False
>>> '_Boo__x' in dir(b)
True
```

So, when you do this:

```
>>> b.__x = 2
```

You're not changing the value of the attribute the `getx` function is looking at, you're creating a *new* attribute.

If you just use a name for the attribute that doesn't start with two underscores—such as `_x`—everything works as you intended.

As a general rule, use a single underscore for "advisory private"—as in, "users of this object probably shouldn't care about this value", and a double underscore only when you actually need mangling (because of complex inheritance issues that rarely come up).

What if you want "real private", like C++ or Java? You can't have it. If you hide or protect the attribute well enough, someone will just monkeypatch the `getx` method or the `x` property. So, Python doesn't give a way to hide attributes.

Comment: Ah! That's that name mangling thing I heard about. I didn't realize it was so literal. After doing `b._Boo__x = 2` `b.x` gave me `2`. (Also, I didn't think to refer to the thing as `x`, but your answer made me curious.)

Comment: @2rs2ts: Exactly. The rule of thumb is: Never use double-underscore names unless you want name mangling. And if you don't understand name mangling, you never want it. Once you do understand name mangling, you want it for a few days just for fun, and then never use it again. :)

Comment: In response to your last edit - I think what I wanted was to refer to the attribute as `x`, and not allow changes to it. I understand now that there's actually two properties here...

Comment: It's not possible to "not allow changes to it". Even if you manage to hide the real attribute away somewhere, someone can just replace your `x` property, or the `getx` method it relies on.

Comment: That's why when I try to give the property the same name as the attribute in `__init__()`, I get the `AttributeError` in `__init__()`, right? Because the definition of `__x` as that property has already set its behavior, before any `Boo` object gets constructed, if I understand correctly?

Comment: @2rs2ts: Exactly. In your second version, when the class definition finishes, `Boo.__dict__['__x']` is the property, so when you try to assign to `self.__x` in an instance, it tries to call that property's `__set__`, which raises that error.

Comment: I understand completely! Plus, while noodling around with this, I was able to create a class-level constant (sort of like a `static final`) string by definining a function `gets(self): return "hello"` and defining `s = property(gets)`. The typical warning about being able to change objects no matter how much I try to prevent that is noted, though.

Comment: @2rs2ts: For real fun, try implementing a `__getattribute__` method in the class. (`if attr=='s': return "Hello"`, else fall through to the normal mechanism.) Then, nobody can assign to `boo_inst.s` without monkeypatching `Boo` (e.g., `if attr=='s' and self is boo_inst: return "Goodbye"` else call the previous function) or changing `boo_inst.__class__`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that using double underscore attribute names *mangles the name*. So when you are dealing with `__x` inside of your class definition, outside of the class it actually looks like `_Boo__x`. That is,

> _ + (class name) + (double underscore attribute name)

To demonstrate,

```
>>> b = Boo(1)
>>> b.__x = 2
>>> b.getx()
1
>>> b.x            # NOTE: same as calling getx
1
>>> b.__x          # why didn't x return 2 if we changed it?
2
>>> b._Boo__x      # because it's actually saved in this attribute
1
>>> b._Boo__x = 3  # setting it here then works
>>> b.x
3
>>> b.getx()
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Really just wanted to comment (rather than answer) your question. I think you will find the following informative:

```
>>> b = Boo(1)
>>> print b.__dict__
{'_Boo__X': 1}
>>> b.__x = 2
>>> print b.__dict__
{'__x': 2, '_Boo__X': 1}
```

Might provide a hint as to the behavior (which I do not understand sufficiently well to explain).

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't have a setx function defined.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class Boo(object):

        def __init__(self, initialize_x):
                self.x = initialize_x

        def getx(self):
                print
                print '\t\tgetx: returning the value of x', self.__x
                print
                return self.__x

        def setx(self, new_x):
                print
                print '\t\tsetx: setting x to new value',new_x
                print
                self.__x = new_x

        x = property(getx, setx)

print '1  ########'
print
print '\tinitializing Boo object with a default x of 20'
print
o = Boo(20)
print '\treading the value of x through property o.x'
t = o.x
print

print '2  ########'
print
print '\tsetting x\'s value through the property o.x'
o.x = 100
print


print '3  ########'
print
print '\treading the value of x through the property o.x'
t = o.x
```

When run produces:

```
1  ########

    initializing Boo object with a default x of 20


        setx: setting x to new value 20

    reading the value of x through property o.x

        getx: returning the value of x 20


2  ########

    setting x's value through the property o.x

        setx: setting x to new value 100


3  ########

    reading the value of x through the property o.x

        getx: returning the value of x 100
```

Comment: I think a `setx` defeats the purpose of my having a read-only attribute, but I guess I could have such a function raise an exception to help emphasize the read-only behavior.

Comment: Although I understand why not having a `setx` could affect that assignment style.

Answer (score -1):

I use `property` as decorator. It convenient for calculating data.

May be for make read-only attribute better use magic function as `__set__` and `__get__`?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.